# Slow mysql query with joins

Tags: mysql, performance

I have to run this query and it is pretty slow (4.86 seconds):

```
SELECT DISTINCT (users.id), users . * 
FROM users
LEFT JOIN user_stages ON users.id = user_stages.user_id
LEFT JOIN user_tags ON users.id = user_tags.user_id
LEFT JOIN log ON log.user_id = users.id
ORDER BY last_activity DESC
```

When I do profiling it looks like Copying to tmp table takes 91% of the time (3.710409 seconds).

The size of the tables: users - almost 100,000 records, log - 1,443,000 records, user_stages - 66,000 records, user_tags - 260,000 records.

There are indexes properly added, if you want I can write all the indexes. How can I rewrite the query or modify the mysql settings to make this query faster?

Comment: Is `users.id` unique?

Comment: You should only select the fields you need, not all (`users . *`)

Comment: Please post the table schema.

Comment: What should the query show?

Comment: Let EXPLAIN PLAN tell you what it's doing.  Don't you want a WHERE clause for a particular user ID somewhere?  This will always involve all the users.  What's your intent?

Comment: Why are you joining at all actually? You are only selecting user fields.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming `last_activity` is in the `users` table, you can change the query to the following:

```
SELECT users.* 
FROM users 
ORDER BY last_activity DESC
```

Your query is selecting only columns from the `users` table.  The `left join` ensures that all rows from the table appear at least once.  The `distinct` is removing duplicates added by the other tables.  Hence, the joins are unnecessary.

If `last_activity` is in another table, then you might need to join that information in.

Your joins are probably taking so much time because you are getting cross products of rows for each user from the various tables.

Comment: Good point, he can remove the joins he does not need. But if he can't remove them all he should GROUP instead of using DISTINCT as it is faster.

Comment: @tntu . . . Why do you think that `group by` is faster than `distinct`?  Do you have a reference as to when/why it is faster?

Comment: Personal experience. If I am wrong, please provide some arguments. I'm always eager to learn.

Comment: @tntu . . . In most databases, the algorithm for `distinct` uses the same algortihm as `group by`.  There may be some minor efficiencies for the `distinct`, because there are no additional aggregated columns, but the performance would often be very similar.

Comment: I only found GROUP BY to be significantly faster then DISTINCT in one case. The query was very long and the data in three of the 11 tables was in the order of millions. The performance of GROUP BY was significant.

Comment: @tntu . . . If you see this again, look at the execution plans.  `distinct` might allow some extra optimizations that are, sometimes, suboptimal.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT `users`.* 
  FROM `users` 
    LEFT JOIN `user_stages` ON `users`.`id` = `user_stages`.`user_id` 
    LEFT JOIN `user_tags` ON `users`.`id` = `user_tags`.`user_id` 
    LEFT JOIN `log` ON `log`.`user_id` = `users`.`id` 
  GROUP BY `users`.`id`
  ORDER BY `last_activity` DESC;
```

Answer (score 0):

The query is built on the fly based on user's input. Sometimes it looks like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT (users.id), users . * 
FROM users
LEFT JOIN user_stages ON users.id = user_stages.user_id
LEFT JOIN user_tags ON users.id = user_tags.user_id
LEFT JOIN log ON log.user_id = users.id
WHERE user_stages.stage_id = 5
AND user_tags.tag_id = 10
ORDER BY last_activity DESC
```

The query has been written using GROUP BY initially but it was slower (about 8 seconds). I replaced GROUP BY with DISTINCT and it was faster but not fast enough. If you have any suggestions I would appreciate.